# How do you calculate the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor with multiple dielectrics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance, electronics, dielectric

My question is how would you go about calculating the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor which has two mediums in between the parallel plates. I am aware that for a regular parallel plate capacitor you can calculate its capacitance with the following equation:

\begin{equation}
C=\varepsilon\frac{A}{d}
\end{equation}

However, for a capacitor as the one shown in the following image, this equation is not applicable because there are multiple dielectrics.

[image: Parallel plate capacitor with multiple dielectrics]

My guess is that you could do something like this (assuming both dielectrics are equal volume):

\begin{equation}
C=\frac{\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2}{2}\frac{A}{d}
\end{equation}

Is this correct? otherwise, what would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What is the basic definition capacitance? What happens to voltage when we stack one dielectric wafer on another?

Comment: What is your background knowledge? Do you know Gauss' theorem? Are you familiar with the vector $\vec{D}$?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

imagine a plate between two dielectric materials, now this plates seperates two dielectric and we can assume them as two seperate parallel plate capacitors connected in series

equivalent capacitance is $1/c=1/c1+1/c2$

Comment: Please don't just answer homework-like questions like this. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange